# Jquery div box show and hide issue

Tags: jquery

Following is my jquery code which hide and showing each div box by clicking on each link. For example there 3 link

1) normal search
2) Advance search
3) project

each div box has 2 link.

So, At first it's showing first div content with **Advance** and **project** link.

If I click on **Advance** link it's showing **second** div box. If click **Normal** link it's showing fist div box BUT if click on ***project*** link then I can't go to **advance** or **normal** link.  And all effect should be like top to bottom down.

Here is jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vrtt0f9q/

```
<div id="first">
    <p>First div and normal search content</p>
    <b><a id="advanceSearch">Advance Search</a> |
    <a id="project">Project</a></b>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <p>Second div and advance serach content.</p>
    <b><a id="normalSearch">Normal Search</a> |
    <a id="project">Project</a></b>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <p>third div and project search content.</p>
    <b><a id="advanceSearch">Advance Search</a> | 
    <a id="normalSearch">Normal Search</a> |
    </b>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //$("#first").slideUp("fast");
    $("#second").slideUp("fast");
    $("#third").slideUp("fast");

    //project
    // advance search
    $("#project").click(function() {
        $("#first").slideUp("slow", function() {
            $("#third").slideDown("slow");          
        });
    });
    // advance search
    $("#advanceSearch").click(function() {
        $("#first").slideUp("slow", function() {
            $("#second").slideDown("slow");         
        });
    });
    //normal search search
    $("#normalSearch").click(function() {
        $("#second, #third").slideUp("slow", function() {
            $("#first").slideDown("slow");                                  
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** - use class instead of id

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t66ruq2p/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny what was the exact problem ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can I make the effect like top to bottom sliding ? and when I click each like it's  move to down from top why ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Now it's Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `id` must be unique, otherwise they will conflicts try this,

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
    <p>First div and normal search content</p>
    <b><a class="advanceSearch">Advance Search</a> |
    <a class="project">Project</a></b>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <p>Second div and advance serach content.</p>
    <b><a class="normalSearch">Normal Search</a> |
    <a class="project">Project</a></b>
</div>

<div id="third">
    <p>third div and project search content.</p>
    <b><a class="advanceSearch">Advance Search</a> | 
    <a class="normalSearch">Normal Search</a> |
    </b>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$("#first").slideUp("fast");
    $("#second").slideUp("fast");
    $("#third").slideUp("fast");

    //project
    // advance search
    $(".project").click(function () {
        $("#first").slideUp("slow", function () {
            $("#third").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
    // advance search
    $(".advanceSearch").click(function () {
        $("#first").slideUp("slow", function () {
            $("#second").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
    //normal search search
    $(".normalSearch").click(function () {
        $("#second, #third").slideUp("slow", function () {
            $("#first").slideDown("slow");
        });
    });

});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/vrtt0f9q/1/)

If you don't need of `slideup()` then you can use `hide()` or `fadeOut()` see the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/vrtt0f9q/3/)

Comment: Can I make the effect like top to bottom sliding only ? and when I click each link it's move the whole div from top  to down why ?